# MYSQL ¿Como puedo meter los Ids de una tabla en un 'array' para luego recorrerlo con un loop y mandar el Id a un procedimiento almacenado?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, stored-procedure

este es mi primera pregunta y buscando en las preguntas relacionadas no encontré algo parecido... Así que prosigo con la pregunta.

Mi duda es la siguiente, necesito crear un procedimiento que calcule todos los montos del mes pasado y meterlo a una tabla llamada "HistorialVentas" para poder consultarlo en el dashboard del front. El problema es que me han pedido realizar una tarea que se ejecute todos los 01 de cada mes cosa que ya tenemos todas los montos del mes pasado y el dashboard simplemente consulta a esa tabla y ya no recalcula todo nuevamente.

El problema está en la DB. Mi procedimiento de calcular e insertar a la tabla historial ya está hecho, necesita dos parámetros, IdSucursal y Fecha (que va a ser el primero de cada mes). El problema es que necesito obtener todos los IdSucursal de la tabla y mandarlos al sp algo tipo [call ERP.spHistorialVentasIngresarMontosMesAnterior(IdSucursal1,fecha)] luego la misma llamada al sp pero con IdSucursal2, IdSucursal3... hasta el ultimo Id Que exista en la taba IdSucursal.

Por lo pronto tengo esto:
[image: No sé cómo obtener los Ids de las sucursales y como mandarlos al sp de manera dinámica]

En resumen: No sé cómo obtener los Ids de las sucursales y como mandarlos al sp de manera dinámica. Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Saludos. Te sugiero para los IDs de las sucursales crear una tabla temporal o mediante un `CURSOR` obtenerlos y recorrerlo. Ya que en tu imagen no se ve que quieres hacer dentro del SP otra opción es que trabajes un SQL que te devuelva todo (lo valides) y al final lo coloques en un `INSERT` (como corresponda) para agregarlo al historial.

Comment: Tienes razon, me ayudó la idea del cursor. muchas gracias! :D